# Date to Excel timestamp

Tags: date, groovy, timezone

I need to calculate an Excel "timestamp" (reference 01.01.1900, not 1970 like the unix timestamp) ; here what I did:

```
Date mydate = new Date();
unixTimestamp = mydate.getTime() / 1000;
excelTimestamp = unixTimestamp / 86400;

def startPoint= new GregorianCalendar(1900, Calendar.JANUARY, 0, 0,0,0).time;

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");

howmany = tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

excelTimeStamp = (unixTimestamp - startPoint.time/1000) / 86400;
```

the latter returns 1 day less, and 1 hour more... what did I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was MUCH easier:

```
Date mydate = new Date();

unixTimestamp = mydate.getTime() / 1000;

TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin");

howmany = tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) / 1000;

excelTimeStamp = 25569 + (unixTimestamp+howmany)/86400;
```